# cakePHP Resources(js, css, img) not being loaded from theme folders

Tags: cakephp, themes

**What I did**

I wrote this code in a index.ctp `$this->Html->css('default')` located at

> /Views/Themed/{THEME NAME}/layout/index.ctp

the code tries to access a default.css located at

> /Views/Themed/{THEME NAME}/webroot/css/default.css

**What happened**

When the page index.ctp is rendered the translation for `$this->Html->css('default')` is

> /cakePHP/css/default.css

**What I expected to happen**

but it has to be

> /cakePHP/theme/{THEME NAME}/css/default.css

The above problem occurred in LAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you telling cake to use your theme?

```
// controller
public $theme = 'theme_name';

//action
$this->theme = 'theme_name';
```